# Quick proof of Cauchy-Binet Identity

Tags: matrices

I am currently preparing a talk for undergraduates during which I will have to resort to the [Cauchy-Binet Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula). However, I don't expect most of the audience to be familiar with this identity and, since I would like to make my talk as self-contained as possible, I feel I should at least outline some proof. As I have very limited time, I would like that proof to be as short and quickly explainable as possible.

Does anyone know a quick way to prove this identity? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [This argument](https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/M123/cauchy.pdf) seems good enough for a talk (where you can wave hands and show examples). [Bumby's notes](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/notes/cauchy-binet.pdf) give a similar argument, where only one of the two matrices gets disassembled into $0$'s and $1$'s. Alternatively, there is the [standard proof using permutations](http://planetmath.org/cauchybinetformula), spelt out to the last detail in Section 5.5 of [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf).